# configuring mongodb in django app

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am trying with django==1.8 and python==2.7
with these steps for configuring mangoDB

Django-nonrel

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
```

djangotoolbox

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
```

Django MongoDB Engine
You should use the latest Git revision.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
```

and in settings.py adding configuration

```
DATABASES = {
   'default' : {
      'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
      'NAME' : 'my_database'
   }
}
```

but i am getting error when running python manage.py syncdb

ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 127.0.0.1:8086: [Errno 111] Connection refused

any help will be very helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: is MongoDB installed and running in your machine?

Comment: yeah it is running vivekpr+  4211  4196  0 13:46 pts/14   00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongo

Comment: Are you sure mongo server is running on port `8086`? On unix, you can check that via [lsof](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lsof&sektion=8&manpath=linux) command: `lsof -n -i4TCP:8086`

Comment: sorry its not running on 8086. Above steps to install mango db is correct or not?

Comment: please tell how to start it

Comment: that's just your grep. It's not running.....you have to install mongo

Answer (score 0):

You have to install MongoDB, Django only provides the engine but not the database itself. Please follow the tutorial

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/